# $ \ \vec a × \vec b = \vec b × \vec c = \vec c × \vec a $ implies existance of a triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, cross-product

Let$\ \vec a, \vec b, \vec c \ $  be noncollinear vectors. Show that the necesssary and sufficient condition for the existence of a triangle $ABC$ with the properties
$\vec {BC}=\vec a ,\vec {CA}= \vec b , \vec {AB}=\vec c \ \ $is$ \ \vec a × \vec b =
\vec b ×
\vec c =
\vec
c ×
\vec 
a $.

I got the left to right implication by multiplying the relation $\vec a+\vec b + \vec c = \vec 0$ with $\vec b $ and $\vec c$, but for the right to left implication I get that $(\vec a + \vec b + \vec c)\times \vec b = \vec 0$ and I don't know how to prove that $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c=\vec 0$ from here.

Comment: It is **not** true that if $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ are the sides of a triangle, then $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c = 0$

Comment: If the equality $a\times b=b\times c=c\times a$ holds, then $(a+b)\times c=b\times c-c\times a=0$, so $a+b$ is parallel to $c$, whence $a+b+c$ is parallel to $c$.  Similarly, $a+b+c$ is parallel to both $a$ and $b$.  What does this imply?

Comment: The idea is that the equation is circularly symmetric. So if you prove $\,(\vec a + \vec b + \vec c)\times \vec b = \vec 0\,$ then circularly permute the vectors and the same hold for $\,\times \vec c\,$ and $\,\times \vec a\,$. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

I will only prove the necessary part.

Let $\vec{s} = \vec{a}\times\vec{b} = \vec{b}\times\vec{c} = \vec{c}\times\vec{a}$ and $\vec{t} = \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c}$.

We are given $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are non-collinear, so $\vec{b}-\vec{a} \not\parallel \vec{c} - \vec{a}$. This leads to
$$3\vec{s} = \vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{b}\times\vec{c} + \vec{c}\times\vec{a}
= (\vec{b}-\vec{a})\times(\vec{c}-\vec{a}) \ne \vec{0}$$

Notice $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{s} = \vec{a} \cdot (\vec{a}\times \vec{b}) = 0$ and similarly, $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{s} = \vec{c} \cdot \vec{s} = 0$. We have

$$\vec{t}\cdot \vec{s} = (\vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c})\cdot \vec{s} = 0$$

Recall the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) for [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product),
$$\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) + \vec{b} \times (\vec{c}\times\vec{a}) + \vec{c} \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) = \vec{0}$$
We have
$$\vec{t} \times \vec{s} = \vec{a} \times \vec{s} + \vec{b} \times \vec{s} + \vec{c} \times \vec{s} = \vec{0}$$

This leads to
$$|\vec{t}|^2||\vec{s}|^2 = (\vec{t}\cdot \vec{s})^2 + | \vec{t} \times \vec{s}|^2 = 0$$

Since $\vec{s} \ne \vec{0}$, $|\vec{s}| \ne 0$ and this forces $|\vec{t}| = 0$.
As a result, $\vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} = \vec{t} = \vec{0}$.